How to plot 2 categorical variables in a dodged barplot with their own subcategories stacked, with a line of a numerical variable on top?
I am trying to make a plot in R to show the frequency of two variables in different periods. My issue is that both variables have different subcategories. Also, I would like to add a third numerical variable in the form of a line depicting the number of events of said variable in the same periods.
So far, I have made a stacked barplot of one variable, but I cannot dodge the other variable. Here´s a hand-drawn example of what I want to do to clarify my question.
This is my code. I am stuck trying to combine both into "md". Right now I can only plot "tromboprofil" with the linedata.
tromboprofil <- structure(list(Period = c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                             "2012-2017", "2018-2023"), 
                             Aspirin=c(1,44,30,12), 
                             VKA=c(3,4,24,20),DOAC=c(NA,NA,1,23),Heparin = c(NA,1,4,NA), None =c(33,7,16,13)), 
                        .Names = c("Period","Aspirin", "VKA", "DOAC", 
                                   "Heparin", "None"), 
                        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))

tratamiento_mieloma<- structure(list(Period = c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                                "2012-2017", "2018-2023"), 
                                     IMID=c(12,41,46,44), 
                                     IP=c(NA,3,16,45),Alquilante=c(19,27,65,42),QT_comb = c(14,1,1,NA), 
                                     Dexa_baja =c(NA,NA,NA,1), Dexa_alta=c(19,43,60,52)), 
                                .Names = c("Period","IMID", "IP", "Alquilante", "QT_comb",
                                           "Dexa_baja", "Dexa_alta"), 
                                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))

tromboprofil$Period <- factor(tromboprofil$Period,ordered = TRUE,
                                 levels = c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                            "2012-2017", "2018-2023"))

tratamiento_mieloma$Period <- factor(tratamiento_mieloma$Period,ordered = TRUE,
                                     levels = c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                                "2012-2017", "2018-2023"))

md <- melt(tromboprofil, id=(c("Period")))

line_data = data.frame(Thrombosis = c(2, 7, 4, 3), Period = unique(md$Period))

ggplot(data = md,
       aes(x = factor(Period,level=c("1997-2005", "2006-2011", 
                                     "2012-2017", "2018-2023")),
           y = value,
           fill = variable))+
  labs(fill="Thromboprophylaxis")+
  geom_col()+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")+
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(y), group = Period), 
            stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  ) +
  geom_line(data = line_data,
            aes(x = Period, y = Thrombosis), 
            color = "black", group = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            size=1)


Here's a hack, since I don't know a better way to combine three unusual features you're seeking here:

dodged + stacked bars, typically done in ggplot2 using stacked bars + facets
line that spans categories, which is tricky across facets
multiple fill scales

#3 is often best done with ggnewscale.
For 1+2, I use patchwork to overlay two plots. This can also be done using grid. Alternatively, one could manually compute the bar locations (dodged on x, stacked on y) and use geom_tile. That is more work but could potentially be more flexible.
library(tidyverse); library(patchwork)
bind_rows(
  pivot_longer(tratamiento_mieloma, -Period) |> mutate(var = "tratamiento\nmieloma"),
  pivot_longer(tromboprofil, -Period) |> mutate(var = "tromboprofil")
) -> combined

line_data = data.frame(Thrombosis = c(2, 7, 4, 3), Period = unique(md$Period))

combined |>
  ggplot(aes(var, value)) +

  geom_col(aes(fill = name),
           position = position_stack(),
           data = . %>% filter(var == "tratamiento\nmieloma")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", name = "tratamiento\nmieloma") + 
  
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(aes(fill = name),
           position = position_stack(),
           data = . %>% filter(var == "tromboprofil")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3", name = "tromboprofil") + 
  facet_wrap(~Period, nrow = 1) +
  
  patchwork::inset_element(
    line_data |>
      ggplot(aes(Period, Thrombosis, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() + 
      theme_void(),
    left = -0.03, bottom = 0, right = 1.03, top = 1
  )


(maybe add expand_limits(y=0) to the 2nd plot if you want the 0 to align between the two plots.)

Thank you! This is very helpful. I tried running this code, but I got the following warning message: "Error in Ops.data.frame(guide_loc, panel_loc) :
‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames"                  Any ideas about this?

That might be a ggplot2 bug from version 3.4.4.9000 and its interaction with patchwork? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5619. Might be fixable by updating patchwork: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5612
